# go - Are "http.Transport" and "http.Client" safe for concurrent modification in Go?

Tags: go, go-http

According to `http.Client` and `http.Transport` documentation in Go's built-in `net/http` package:

```
// The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP
// connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as
// needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.
```

So I just wonder: is it safe for concurrent modification too or not? since **I wanna perform 20K** `http.Request` with single `http.Client` struct and different values concurrently, not consecutively.

Comment: It is not safe for the application to modify client or transport fields concurrently.  It is safe to execute requests on a client and transport concurrently.

Comment: No values are safe for concurrent modification.

Comment: It helps to consider there's no magic: the types in question are safe for concurrent _use_ which means _reading_ their fields and calling their methods which implement synchronisation where needed. Writing fields of values of the types in question while these fields are read concurrently would create plain old boring data races. Hence the answer to your question is no.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, `http.Client` is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines, which means you can use a single http.Client instance to perform multiple HTTP requests concurrently from different goroutines